# What does MetaMask mean by stop injecting web3.js?

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps, browsers, chain-reorganization

MetaMask announced that they will stop injecting web3.js [here](https://medium.com/metamask/no-longer-injecting-web3-js-4a899ad6e59e). I know previously MetaMask will add a global variable in browser `window.web3` and this global lowercase `web3` variable will be deprecated soon. But in my DApp, I use MetaMask as a provider to the original `Web3.js` library (i.e. captical `Web3`). Will my usage be affected by MetaMask stopping injecting web3.js?

I also posted another question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79962/web3-js-eth-subscribe-onchanged-functionevent-doesnt-work-with-metama#comment98678_79978), where I find web3.js cannot listen to `on("changed")` events in smart contract using MetaMask offered provider `ethereum`. If I still want to use MetaMask and Web3.js in my DApp, how can I get notified when events emitted in smart contracts are removed due to chain reorganization?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If MetaMask will stop injecting web3 this means `web3.currentProvider` is not gonna work anymore properly. My advice is to handle the change and not getting your app crashed by downloading your own web3 library and using `ethereum` provider. This variable was introduced in the latest versions. Example:

```
const Web3 = require('web3'); // import web3 v1.0 constructor from node_modules
if(window.ethereum) {
    const web3Instance = new Web3(window['ethereum']);

    var methods = {
        getAddressETHBalance: function(address)    {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                resolve(web3Instance.eth.getBalance(address));
            });
        }
    };

    methods.getAddressETHBalance(<ADDRESS>);
} else {
    alert('Missing MetaMask extention.');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MiroslavNedelchev. I noticed that web3.js requires `ws` provider to subscribe events in smart contracts and MetaMask uses `http` connection to ethereum node. Will that be affected if I get web3 in this way `const web3Instance = new Web3(window['ethereum']);`?

Comment: I'm using ```const web3Instance = new Web3(window['ethereum']);``` in my dApps and I have no problems in getting events or listening to them.

Comment: I can listen to events and get notified when new events are emitted. But I cannot get notified when events are removed due to reorg. Are you also be able to listen to removed events?